# What is the best way to upload files to a WCF service using AJAX and Angular?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, wcf, sharepoint

I am using AngularJs to submit a form to a Sharepoint WCF service. 
What is the best way to upload file attachments using AJAX, supporting all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is for AngularJs as frontend and NodeJs as backend. but you can also use it with .net and WCF as backend if you are using Angular for ajax request. please follow the link below

https://ciphertrick.com/2015/12/07/file-upload-with-angularjs-and-nodejs/